How to browse videos in iPhone backup?
I have videos taken by my iPhone and stored in the camera roll and photos library.
I use macos' photos app to import and view these videos on macos. I don’t use iCloud for videos/photos.
I’m assuming my regular iphone backup files (encrypted) have those videos already, So I presume I have a lot of duplicate files
if I find a way to browse those videos from ios backup file on macos, then that would be great.
How can I do that?
